# Qt Application shows build error in Debug mode, OK in release mode

Tags: qt, debugging, build, static, mingw

I have Qt (I think 4.8.4) 32-bit statically compiled on my 64-bit Windows 7. The compiler I am using is MinGW 32-bit (mingw32-make.exe). When I build it statically in release mode, files are generated succefully in the following directory:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Project-build-Unnamed_Microsoft_Windows_SDK_for_Windows_7_7_1_7600_0_30514_x86-Release
```

However, when I try to build it in Debug mode, it gives me the following compile errors

```
cannot find -lqtmaind
cannot find -lQtGuid
cannot find -lQtNetworkd
cannot find -lQtCored
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please let me know what I can do to access the debug features. Also, what changes shall I have to make in my configuration so that I am able to build my project dynamically as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed qt, did you configure it to install static debug libraries also. If not then try reconfiguring and reinstalling it. In windows, I think you installed from a preconfigured, precompiled binary that may not have static debug support. Try downloading the source and then configure and compile it according to your needs

Comment: Thanks for the tip Abhishek. I'll try re-installing Qt.